# Can I statically reject different instantiations of an existential type?

Tags: haskell, existential-type, gadt, type-level-computation

#### First attempt

It's difficult to make this question pithy, but to provide a minimal example, suppose I have this type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Val where
  Val :: Eq a => a -> Val
```

This type lets me happily construct the following heterogeneous-looking list:

```
l = [Val 5, Val True, Val "Hello!"]
```

But, alas, when I write down an `Eq` instance, things go wrong:

```
instance Eq Val where
  (Val x) == (Val y) = x == y -- type error
```

Ah, so we `Could not deduce (a1 ~ a)`. Quite right; there's nothing in the definition that says `x` and `y` must be the same type. In fact, the whole point was to allow the possibility that they differ.

#### Second attempt

Let's bring `Data.Typeable` into the mix, and only try comparing the two if they happen to be the same type:

```
data Val2 where
  Val2 :: (Eq a, Typeable a) => a -> Val2

instance Eq Val2 where
  (Val2 x) == (Val2 y) = fromMaybe False $ (==) x <$> cast y
```

This is pretty nice. If `x` and `y` are the same type, it uses the underlying `Eq` instance. If they differ, it just returns `False`. However, this check is delayed until runtime, allowing `nonsense = Val2 True == Val2 "Hello"` to typecheck without complaint.

#### Question

I realize I'm flirting with dependent types here, but is it possible for the Haskell type system to statically reject something like the above `nonsense`, while allowing something like `sensible = Val2 True == Val2 False` to hand back `False` at runtime?

The more I work with this problem, the more it seems I need to adopt some of the techniques of [HList](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/HList/) to implement the operations I need as type-level functions. However, I am relatively new to using existentials and GADTs, and I am curious to know whether there's a solution to be found just with these. So, if the answer is no, I'd very much appreciate a discussion of exactly where this problem hits the limit of those features, as well as a nudge toward appropriate techniques, HList or otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want a constructor that allows you to use heterogeneous types, but you want comparisons between heterogeneous types that are *knowable* at compile time to be rejected.  As in:

```
Val True == Val "bar"  --> type error

allSame [] = True
allSame (x:xs) = all (== x) xs

allSame [Val True, Val "bar"]  --> False
```

But surely:

```
(x == y) = allSame [x,y]
```

So I'm pretty sure a function with satisfies these constraints would violate some desirable property of a type system.  Doesn't it look like that to you?  I am strongly guessing "no, you can't do that".

Comment: This is a very illuminating example, as it gets closer to the real application I have in mind, and shows me just how much I am asking of the type system here. Do you have any thoughts about whether HList would be appropriate if the desired behavior is to statically reject something like that example call to `allSame`?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what HList is for.  In exchange, working with lists gets a lot less flexible. I consider appeals to such high amounts of type system trickery to be a design smell -- Haskell is at its best in bringing out the simplicity of your problem.  But that's a personal preference.

Comment: Indeed, and it's one that I share. A first cut at the full problem I'm tackling here, embedding a logic programming language, is delightfully simple if you treat `Val` as a standard sum type. However, it's closed to extension and offers no static checking that unifications in the language are sensible. I'm working with `syb` to address the first problem, and this question is my stab at the second.

Comment: @acfoltzer, ah, I get it.  I've tried to do the same thing.  It's hard -- thus why [Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_(programming_language)) split off into its own language, probably.

Answer (score 14):

In order to make type-checking decisions based on the contained types, we need to "remember" the contained type by exposing it as a type parameter.

```
data Val a where
  Val :: Eq a => a -> Val a
```

Now `Val Int` and `Val Bool` are different types, so we can easily enforce that only same-type comparisons are allowed.

```
instance Eq (Val a) where
  (Val x) == (Val y) = x == y
```

However, since `Val Int` and `Val Bool` are different types, we cannot mix them together in a list without an additional layer which "forgets" the contained type again.

```
data AnyVal where
  AnyVal :: Val a -> AnyVal

-- For convenience
val :: Eq a => a -> AnyVal
val = AnyVal . Val
```

Now, we can write

```
[val 5, val True, val "Hello!"] :: [AnyVal]
```

It should hopefully be clear by now that you cannot meet both requirements with a single data type, as doing so would require both "forgetting" *and* "remembering" the contained type at the same time.

Comment: Using the word "forgets" with `AnyVal` is very helpful. Unfortunately, it further convinces me that I'm asking too much of the type system. What I want apparently is a type that forgets long enough to be in a heterogeneous collection, but then conveniently remembers as soon as I need to know the contained type.